# Raise an error during process within iterator and continue to next item

Tags: ruby, error-handling

Lets say I am looping over some items in an array like so:

```
class ImportHandler

attr_reader :files

 def initialize
   @files = ['file_path','file_path2']
 end

 def process
    files.each do |file|
     begin
      if validate(file) && decrypt(file)
       import(file)
       upload(file)
      end
     rescue Exception => e
      raise e
     end
    end
 end

 def validate(file)
  FileValidator.new(file).run
 end
end
```

All of the operations you see above like validate, decrypt, import, and upload are methods that create a new object.

Lets say within any of these steps something could fail (whether the file isn't valid, can't be decrypted etc.). I want to raise an error in any of these processes, yet make sure that it comes back (returns to the class where the iteration is taking place) and continues to the next file path in the array.

For instance in the validate class (which is the class for validate if that isn't clear in the example above), I may have something like this:

```
class FileValidator

   attr_reader :file

    def initialize(file)
      @file = file
    end

   def hash_validation(file_path)
     unless file.hash == metdata_hash
       raise "This file has been tampered with!"
     end
   end
end
```

I want to raise that error but make sure that the program returns back to the iteration, and continues to the next object in the array. Is there an easy way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the code in  begin/rescue/end and the rescue will catch the error, then continue to with the next iteration:

```
files.each do |file|
  begin
    if validate(file) && decrypt(file)
     import(file)
     upload(file)
    end
  rescue
   // do nothing or maybe provide some output to know that error occured
  end
end
```

Also there's a `retry` you can call from rescue to try again with the current iteration. of course you might need some condition like retry count, etc. to make sure you don't fall into infinite loop.

Comment: I have something like that but the program still stops running if an error occurs.

Comment: Can you show what you have? what kind of error occurs when it stops?

Comment: `rescue` can be followed by a parameter list of exceptions to catch (e.g., `ArgumentError`); if no parameters follow, the error type defaults to `StandardError`.  You can also have separate `rescue` clauses for different errors and, following each parameter list you can add `=> var_name`, in which case Ruby will assign the error message to the variable you specify.

Comment: Graham, please be specific about the error: what is the error message and which line of your code triggers it?

Comment: I updated my original question with more code to show my setup.

Comment: You are re-raising the error in rescue block.just remove `raise e`